# What is the meaning of using proxy ( dynamic proxy) in spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, dynamic-proxy

I don't know the meaning of using proxy in spring. what is efficient?

Comment: what do you mean "what is efficient?"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [dynamic proxy](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) is a feature of the JDK. It can be used to implement an interface using [an invocation handler](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html).

> A dynamic proxy class (simply referred
>   to as a proxy class below) is a class
>   that implements a list of interfaces
>   specified at runtime when the class is
>   created, with behavior as described
>   below. A proxy interface is such an
>   interface that is implemented by a
>   proxy class. A proxy instance is an
>   instance of a proxy class. Each proxy
>   instance has an associated invocation
>   handler  object, which implements the
>   interface InvocationHandler.

A dynamic proxy has some overhead. For most use cases the overhead won't be significant, though. The real problem is that the (over)use of dynamic proxies makes an application harder to understand and debug. For example a dynamic proxy will show up with mulitple lines in a stacktrace.

Dynamic proxies are often used to implement [decorators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). One example of this is AOP in Spring. (I don't want to go into the details of [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) and won't use AOP terminology to keep things simple). Where certain concerns are implemented in one class and used in many places. The dynamic proxies (and invocation handlers) are only the glue code (provided by Spring) to intercept the method calls. (Actually, dynamic proxies are only an implementation detail of this capability. Generating classes on the fly is another possibility to implement it.)

Comment: Why do we implement that? I want to ask about methology or same things

Answer (score 64):

Proxies are used by [AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction). In short:

Normally you have.

```
Caller --> Real object
```

But when, for example, you want automatic transaction management, spring puts a proxy of your real object

```
Caller --> Proxy --> Real object
```

where the proxy starts the transaction.

[Here is nice article](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/07/19/debunking-myths-proxies-impact-performance/) explaining both the essence of proxies and their efficiency (performance) in spring

Comment: Bozho, it's a very nice explanation.

Comment: next question - why spring need to use aop? I know only @Transaction annotation

Comment: Many other things. Caching, for example. Logging. Audit trail. Or whatever else you can develop yourself

Answer (score 2):

We can add a functionality to Java class by modifying the source/byte code or by using subclass or proxy which embeds the additional functionality and delegates the calls to underlying object.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are good, but here's how I think of it in very simple terms.

1. An annotation means "add hidden code for extra behavior."
2. The framework (or whatever knows what the annotation means) adds bytecode, Spring at runtime, AspectJ at compile time, for example.
3. It adds code as a proxy along with an interceptor. (A wrapper, decorator, adapter are similar and may be easier to understand than "proxy".)
4. When the program runs, the interceptor sends execution to the proxy which does its thing, which then may or may not send execution to the class that you coded and that it "wraps".

Answer (score 0):

AOP can also use CGLIB proxies. This is used to proxy the classes instead of interfaces.

Comment: but this can happen only if the proxied class (or methods) are not `final` - This is because CGLIB uses subclassing (inheritance) to create proxies.