# org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod: getBean().getClass() vs getBeanType()

Tags: annotations

I have to get the annotations attached to a controller class.
this is the controller:

```
@Tag(name = "Unita Offerta", description = "Rest Controller per unita offerta")
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = { "/protected/unita-di-offerta" })
@Validated
@ProfiloSelezionato
public class UnitaOffertaController extends BaseRestController{
```

Now, if I use (clazz is the annotation class)

```
annotation = method.getBeanType().getAnnotation(clazz);
```

it works fine, but if I use

```
annotation = method.getBean().getClass().getAnnotation(clazz);
```

I can't get the annotation.

Reading the documentation I know that *.getBeanType()* returns the type of the handler
while  `.getBean().getClass()` returns the bean (as object class) and then the runtime class.

But I expected that the runtime class was more accurated or more or less the same of the type of the handler got through `.getBeanType()`.

At runtime, debugging the code, I can read that
`.getBean().getClass()` returns

> <package>.UnitaOffertaController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dfd1a00a

while
`.getBeanType()` returns

> <package>.UnitaOffertaController.

What is the difference? And why using `.getBean().getClass()` I can't get the annotation

Answer (score 0):

What a great question!

When you are using some extra postprocessors or aop, Spring might enhance your class/bean and as a result it creates a proxy class (recognizable by the weird name, like you rightfully noticed):

```
<package>.UnitaOffertaController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dfd1a00a
```

The thing is this proxy class **DOESN'T** **have the same annotations** as the original class, as it's a completely different class that simply proxies to the original.

You can read more about proxies here: [What is the meaning of using proxy ( dynamic proxy) in spring framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227836/what-is-the-meaning-of-using-proxy-dynamic-proxy-in-spring-framework)

Hope that helps!